# ¿Cómo puedo "reemplazar" el número del ID por el (first_name) del modelo (User) de Django en una lista de la tabla de un template?

Tags: python, django

¿Cómo puedo "reemplazar" el número del ID (Memorando) por el primer nombre (first_name) del modelo de usuario (User) por defecto de Django en una lista de la tabla de un template?
[image: Reemplazar el número por el primer nombre del modelo User de Django]

```
De (ID = de) | Fecha | Asunto

2 | 2/2/2018 | Commentary
```

A esto:

```
De (ID = de) | Fecha | Asunto

Jane | 2/2/2018 | Comentario
```

**view.py**

```
def MemoList(request, usuario):

    instancia = get_object_or_404(Empleado, usuario_id=usuario)

    lista2 = Memorandum.objects.filter(para_id=instancia)


    for usuarios in lista2:
        lista_de_id = usuarios.de_id
        lista_para_id = usuarios.para_id
        lista_asunto = usuarios.asunto
        lista_fecha = usuarios.fecha


    context = {
        "lista2":lista2,
        "lista_de_id": lista_de_id,
        "lista_para_id": lista_para_id,
        "lista_asunto": lista_asunto,
        "lista_fecha" : lista_fecha


    }
    return render(request, 'app/admin/memolist.html',context)
```

**models.py**

```
class Memorandum(models.Model):
    de = models.ForeignKey(User)
    para = models.ForeignKey(Empleado) 
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    detalle = models.TextField()
```

**template**

```
{% for usuarios in lista2 %}
    {{usuarios.de_id}}
    {{usuarios.fecha}}
    {{usuarios.asunto}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Cómo lo estás mostrando en tu template?

Comment: Ya lo he editado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
{% for usuarios in lista2 %}
    {{usuarios.de.first_name }}
    {{usuarios.fecha}}
    {{usuarios.asunto}}
{% endfor %}
```

Si quieres el nombre completo:

```
{% for usuarios in lista2 %}
    {{usuarios.de.get_full_name }}
    {{usuarios.fecha}}
    {{usuarios.asunto}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Gracias. ¡Funciona!